# number palindrome in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

```
#!/bin/sh
echo “Enter number:”
read n
num=$n
rev=0
while [ $num –ne 0 ]
do
rem= `expr $num % 10`
rev= `expr $rev \* 10 + $rem`
num= `expr $num / 10`
done
if [ $rev –eq $n ]
then
echo $n “is a palindrome”
else
echo $n “is not a palindrome”
fi
```

I am getting errors as::

> unary operator expected

Please help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

What an unexpected problem! Your dash `-` character is not the right dash.

The hex representation of your dash `–` is `0xe28093`
[Unicode Character 'EN DASH' (U+2013)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).
But the right dash's hex representation is ASCII `0x2d`.

```
echo -n  '–' | xxd      # 00000000: e280 93
echo -n '-' | xxd       # 00000000: 2d
```

So you should change it to the correct dash.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter number : "
read n

# store single digit
sd=0

# store number in reverse order
rev=""

# store original number
on=$n

while [ $n -gt 0 ]
do
sd=$(( $n % 10 )) # get Remainder 
n=$(( $n / 10 ))  # get next digit
# store previous number and current digit in reverse 
rev=$( echo ${rev}${sd} ) 
done

if [ $on -eq $rev ];
then
echo "Number is palindrome"
else
echo "Number is NOT palindrome"
fi
```

Source : https://bash.cyberciti.biz/academic/palindrome-shell-script/